# F# Raw Sql With TypeProviders

Tags: f#, type-providers

I need to do a select where I decrypt a column value using sql certificate and im currently using type providers (sooo nice :)).

In raw sql this would be like so (more or less):

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY KEYNAME
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE CERTNAME;

SELECT ID, CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByKey(KEYNAME)) AS 'DecyptedData'
FROM dbo.EncryptedData;

CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY SymmetricKey1;
```

I have no interest in creating a view for this purpose.

I would like to do this in F# code, hence the request for raw sql ability (if possible)

An ADO connection is an option, but I would like to use type providers if possible to avoid an extra connection.

Does anyone know if this can be done easily?

Comment: Have you tried SqlCommandProvider? http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/

Comment: Thanks ive seen it but not used it. :) Would like to avoid the extra connection if possible. If not then F#.Data.SqlClient is an option together with pure ADO.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to do this with the type provider and so ended up using FSharp.Data.SqlClient to handle it.

It works like a charm, but with the downside that I now use 2 different providers for accessing data in the same table :).